# Flash ActionScript 3 Code error: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'am the just start learning actionscript 3, follow is my code, when i lauch the code, it still report the error in frame 36 but did not locate the error in which line. please help me debug them.... TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. At flashmo_217_v_shape_fla::MainTimeline/frame36()

Following is the code in frame36

```
stop();
fm_button.visible = false;


import caurina.transitions.*;

var menu_label_North:Array = new Array("Animals Collection", 
                                                                                 "Flowers Collection",
                                                                                 "Leaves Collection",
                                                                                 "Mixed Collection",
                                                                                 "Extra Collection",
                                                                                 "Special Awards",
                                                                                 "Company Background",
                                                                                 "Contact Information");


var total_north:Number = menu_label_North.length;
var i_north:Number = 0;
var page_north:Number;
var main_menu_North:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
stage.addChild(main_menu_North);


for (i_north = 0; i_north < total_north; i_north++)
{
          var btn_north = new flashmo_button();
          btn_north.name = "btn" + i_north;
          btn_north.x = fm_button.x + i_north * ( fm_button.width + 12 );
          btn_north.y = fm_button.y;
          btn_north.buttonMode = true;
          btn_north.item_no = i_north;
          btn_north.flashmo_click_area.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, btn_enter_north );


          var each_substring_north:Array = menu_label_North[i_north].split("|");
          btn_north.flashmo_button_label.fm_label.text = each_substring[0];
          btn_north.item_url = each_substring[1];
          main_menu_North.addChild(btn_north);
}


function btn_over_north(e:MouseEvent):void
{
          e.target.parent.over = true;
}


function btn_out_north(e:MouseEvent):void
{
          e.target.parent.over = false;
}


function btn_click_north(e:MouseEvent):void
{
          var mc= e.target.parent;
          if ( mc.item_url != undefined )
                    navigateToURL( new URLRequest( mc.item_url ), "_parent" );
          else
                    change_page_north(mc.item_no);
}


function btn_enter_north(e:Event):void
{
          var mc_north = e.target.parent;
          if ( mc_north.over == true )
                    mc_north.nextFrame();
          else
                    mc_north.prevFrame();
}


function change_page_north(no:Number):void
{
          for (var i:Number = 0; i < main_menu_North.numChildren; i++)
          {
                    var mc = MovieClip( main_menu_North.getChildAt(i) );
                    mc.over = false;
                    mc.flashmo_click_area.visible = true;
                    mc.flashmo_click_area.addEventListener( MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, btn_over_north );
                    mc.flashmo_click_area.addEventListener( MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, btn_out_north );
                    mc.flashmo_click_area.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_click_north );
          }
          var mc_selected = MovieClip( main_menu_North.getChildAt(no) );
          mc_selected.over = true;
          mc_selected.flashmo_click_area.visible = false;
          mc_selected.flashmo_click_area.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, btn_over_north );
          mc_selected.flashmo_click_area.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, btn_out_north );
          mc_selected.flashmo_click_area.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_click_north );

          page_north = no + 1;
          play();
}


change_page_north(0);// default page on load


flashmo_credit.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, goto_fm_north );


function goto_fm_north(e:MouseEvent):void
{
          navigateToURL( new URLRequest( "http://www.flashmo.com" ), "_parent" );
}


music_credit.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, goto_music_north );


function goto_music_north(e:MouseEvent):void
{
          navigateToURL( new URLRequest(
          "http://www.premiumbeat.com/royalty_free_music/byPiece.php?id=2614" ),
          "_blank" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your error might come from `var mc = MovieClip( main_menu_North.getChildAt(i) );`

The child will should be a `flashmo_button` right? If you use `MovieClip(obj)` you are saying you want to convert `obj` to a `MovieClip`. If it is already a MovieClip (or a descendant of MovieClip) you should use `as MovieClip`.

E.g.

```
var mc:MovieClip = main_menu_North.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip
```

In fact, you should cast it to a `DisplayObject` type since in the future you can't guarantee that it will always be a `MovieClip`.

The other potential area for a potential null object I can see is when using `e.target.parent`. If you are trying to get the clicked button you should use `e.currentTarget` see [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#CLICK). Test if you get an valid object before calling methods on them.

```
if(e.currentTarget && e.currentTarget.parent) {
    // now do something
}
```